# Identify the maximum times consequently happens character and returns the starting index

Tags: java, string, loops, repeat, charat

Here is my code ,

Find me the way to finish this off .
I had this question in paper this is the code at that time I could do.
In following example it should return 3.(starting point of "d")

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){
        int result = getMax("haaddddddddccf");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int getMax(String input){
        int length = input.length();

        int count     = 0;
        int max       = 0;
        int tempCount = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++) {             
            if(input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i+1)) {
                count ++ ;
            }
            tempCount = count;
            count = 0;

            if(max > tempCount) {
               max = tempCount;                 
               return i;                 
            }

            tempCount = 0;
        }
        return 0;           
    }
}
```

Comment: `str.indexOf(<char>)` returns the first index.

Comment: yes ! Thanks .cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){
        int result = getMax("haaddddddddccf");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int getMax(String input){
        int length = input.length();

        int maxIndex  = 0;
        int max       = 0;
        int count     = 1;
        char current  = input.charAt(0);
        int index = 0;

        for(int i=1; i<length-1; i++) {
            if(input.charAt(i) == current) {
                count ++ ;
                if(count > max) {
                    max = count;
                    maxIndex = index;
                }
            }
            else {
                count = 1;
                current = input.charAt(i);
                index = i;
            }                
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

This goes over the entire string and counting consecutive occurrences of characters. If the count goes over the observed maximum, the start index of that series of consecutive characters is saved as well as the number of characters. If the character changes, the current values reset and counting starts over. After going over the entire list, the index of the longest series of consecutive characters is in `maxIndex`.